music loop earlier before completing it's playlength
There is a composition of music which have 5 to 6 audio files and which play simultaneously in the app.
I enabled the loop mode in AudioInstance and the problem is music loops earlier before reaching it's end.
For example: an audio file have duration of 2:22 mins, the music should loop after 2:22 mins but it loops 1:30, 2:00 or 1:80 mins (not fixed duration).
final compositionAudioPlayersJustAudio = <audio.AudioPlayer>[].obs;
    
compositionAudioPlayersJustAudio.addAll(List.generate(data.length,

(index){debugPrint(index.toString());return audio.AudioPlayer();}));


 compositionAudioPlayersJustAudio[index].setLoopMode(audio.LoopMode.one);

data is list of audio files in a composition.
I am expecting music loop when its duration has been completed.
